# Windows 8 MPG codec

Tags: windows-8, video, mpg

Is there any chance to get an MPG codec only for Windows 8 somewhere, instead of all those free multiple codec packages I don't trust so much?

Comment: Why don't you trust those packages? I'd say use the built-in Windows 8 store if you want something vetted (well, I *assume* it's vetted by Microsoft). An individual codec out on the net somewhere is no more trustworthy than a pack of codecs (arguably less, if you're comparing it to a popular codec pack like CCCP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Codec Installation Package. This package can be used as an alternative to automatically downloading Windows Media Codecs, or to correct problems experienced with previously-downloaded codecs. [LINK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=507).

*Install only codecs, filters, or plug-ins from trusted, authorized sources, such as the website of the official supplier. Even then, use caution: some codec suppliers offer minimal customer support. Before installing any digital media components, set a system restore point. The restore point enables you to return to your original system configuration, if necessary. And I think this link is trustable. If you are worried, just create a restore point before. [LINK](http://download.cnet.com/Windows-8-Codecs-Pack/3000-13632_4-75754340.html).

Answer (score 0):

The [Media Center pack for Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/feature-packs) adds MPEG codecs to the operating system. There was a limited time offer when the upgrade was free, but not anymore. If the media center pack is installed, then Windows Store apps are able to use the MPEG codecs as well (not available on Windows RT).

The 'Codec Installation Package' linked in the answer above does not contain MPEG codecs - just Windows Media codecs (which are different from MPEG)

If you want a free solution, my recommendation is to get FFDShow: http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It's all well and good with "normal" Windows where codec packs can be installed, but is there any possibility of expanded codec support in WinRT? Would have been nice if XBox Music, Video and the like supported at least common codecs such as FLAC and MKV out of the box. I know third-party solutions exist (both free and paid), but why do we need to switch to them when audio/video apps of a certain standard are already available out of the box? The price for the codecs could have been included in the device's price. This step-motherly treatment for WinRT is irritating. (Sorry for the rant. :)

Comment: @Karan: Adding additional codec support is always being considered, but has to be prioritized relative to other features. Adding codec support isn't always just a matter of licensing cost - often it is the supporting/servicing cost that is prohibitive (especially because of legacy compat). WinRT is a priority, but it is also a rare opportunity to start with a clean slate and limit legacy (and number of) components to guarantee a solid quality experience. It has been a conscious decision to concentrate on MP4 since FLAC/MKV is more enthusiast than mainstream (I realize this is slowly changing)

Comment: I wouldn't exactly term them "enthusiast"-only now. A few years back, perhaps, especially with little hardware support out there. Now? Even cheap video streamers/media players support these containers/formats, not to mention the millions of mobile/other small form factor devices out there. It would have been nice for MS to have been a bit more forward-thinking in terms of WinRT at least, since we don't even have access to desktop apps. In many ways it does look to the future, but in others it's oddly mired in the past or stuck in the present (which in tech terms is the past in no time at all).